# Is it the only way of URL mapping to select a controller to run?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

The first step, in SpringMVC application, may be mapping a URL to one Controller (not a Jsp page) to display the HomePage using GET method, isn't it? After the form, in my spicific app, is filled, the same controller get the information, do some verifications and the return a logical view name to InternalViewResolver to show the second page.

My question is: when user click a icon or button in the second page, how does the next controller be selected to run? Is still a URL mapping? or any way else?

thanks!
kenneth

Comment: Yes. The browser makes requests, reauests are mapped to a controller method, and the controller method is invoked.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is, Yes. Whether you use ajax request or form submission, you will need to have a controller with appropriate mapping url that will process your request further depending on the code your controller contains.

Answer (score 0):

> when user click a icon or button in the second page, how does the next controller be selected to run? Is still a URL mapping? or any way else?

yes, because Spring MVC uses url pattern which itself is a concise and simple way for mapping set of urls.

When you click image or link in ur view page, you allow Controller and DispatcherServlet to receive user's request and after that dispatch request to controller. Then MappingHandler will choose which one is right url request that client requesting by following `HttpServletRequest` mechanism.

```
public interface HandlerMapping {
  HandlerExecutionChain getHandler(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception;
}
```

After this Controller will do real work of processing request/view page.

Note that: URL pattern itself follow simple ways to run the correct url by analyzing every character in a pattern which must match the corresponding character in the URL path exactly with two exceptions.

In Spring MVC, you can do either this

```
<a href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/othersite"> Other site </a>
```

or that

```
<spring:url value="/othersite"/>
```

then URL pattern will be matched by controller itself.

Comment: Do you means that if I hope my controller or one of its method to do some processes for user while this user click an icon, image, button or link, I must set this icon, image, button or link to a URL format?